# Executing a python script when a terminal is opened within that terminal

Tags: python, terminal

Im interested if there is a way to run a python script when you open a terminal window. For example

```
print "hello world"
```

Every time i open a terminal, hello world would appear.

Comment: Windows? Linux? cygwin? Gnome Terminal? Konsole? xterm? bash? sh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bash, anything you put in your ~/.bashrc file will be run when you open the terminal, i.e.

```
python my_script.py
```

will execute the script my_script.py.

Comment: Hi I did this then did . .bashrc and it executed my program in the window. However, i then opened another terminal and the program didnt run.

Answer (score 0):

> Every time i open a terminal, hello world would appear.

Just do:

```
clrscr("Hello World")                   # or whatever string you want
```

anywhere in any of your python scripts.

To achieve this effect, you have to do the following 2 things

**1-** For sake of portability you have to make a small module as shown below-

```
# goodManners.py
from os import system as command        # for calling to system's terminal
from platform import system as osName   # for getting the OS's name

def clrscr(text):
    if osName()=='Windows':
        command('cls')
    else:
        command('clear')
    print(text)
```

**2-** Now in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pythonstartup
```

and put your python code in $HOME/.pythonstartup, like:

```
from goodManners import clrscr
```